# How to make custom validations in Project Lombok setters

Tags: java, netbeans, lombok

I have a project(ID3 tagging) that contains dozens of setters and getters. I'm investigating Project Lombok to see how it can help me.

Some of the fields that can be set have very strict requirements that could include character encoding, bit-setting, length checks, character ranges and, so on. I could use a builder patter but, there may be cases where the pattern isn't necessary. What if I want to use validation methods and/or classes rather than annotation? How can I access Lombok's setters in my Netbeans project to add these validations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is that you can't.

The only consistency check supported now is `@Nonnull`. If you want anything else, you have to write your setters manually. Obviously, no tool can do all the check you listed and describing them  via annotations would be cumbersome at best.

Sometimes, this [feature request](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/674) could help. It might be too course grained for your needs or not. Quite often, all you need is to write some setters manually. This feature is more useful with immutable objects as it will provide the only way to add validation to generated constructors.

Comment: Agreed with the answer but it would be nice to have support for Javax Validation annotations.

Comment: @coolersport Right, this would be nice. In your case, I'd just write all the validating setters manually and use Lombok for the remaining stuff.

Answer (score 3):

Although validation on setters is not possible as of today but **you can do custom validations on lombok Builder.**

To do this you should override Builder.build method and put your validations there. Sample code snippet looks like below

```
@Getter
@EqualsAndHashCode
@ToString
@Builder(builderClassName = "Builder",buildMethodName = "build")
public class Customer {
    private long id;
    private String name;

    static class Builder {
        Customer build() {
            if (id < 0) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Invaid id");
            }
            if (Objects.isNull(name)) {
                throw new RuntimeException("name is null");
            }
            return new Customer(id, name);
        }
    }
}
```

[source and credit](https://trguduru.github.io/2019/06/add-custom-validations-with-lombok-builders/)

Comment: It's probably better to put the validation in the constructor: 1. otherwise the all args constructor will have no validation 2. the builder often times contains code that is not trivial to reproduce (default values, singular setters for collections).

Comment: Although, if the all args constructor is not public/used, a way to fix #2 would be to add `buildMethodName = "someUglyName"`, and provide your own `build` which is based on `someUglyName`. 
i.e. it calls `someUglyName()`, performs/calls validations and returns the object

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `@Builder` on a constructor and add the validation there.
Upon building the annotated constructor will be used.

example:

```java
@Getter
@EqualsAndHashCode
 class MyDto {

    private final String thisCannotBeNull;
    private final String someOtherValue;
    private final String thisValueCannotBeNull;
    private final String someValue2;

    @Builder
    public CreateOrderRequestDto(@JsonProperty("thisValueCannotBeNull") final String thisValueCannotBeNull,
                                 @JsonProperty("someOtherValue") final String someOtherValue,
                                 @JsonProperty("thisValueCannotBeNull") final String someOtherValue,
                                 @JsonProperty("someValue2") final String someValue2) {
        this.thisCannotBeNull = notNull(thisValueCannotBeNull);
        this.thisValueCannotBeNull = notNull(thisValueCannotBeNull);
        this.someOtherValue = someOtherValue;
        this.someValue2 = someValue2;
    }
}
```

ignore `@JsonProperty` if you are not interested in it. The main idea here is the notNull validation in the constructor